# How to start an Node.JS Web-App

Tags: node.js, web-applications

To start a new project/webapp on Node.js, I need:

- Folder Structure;
- Libraries (Express, RequireJS, Mocha, Bower, ...);
- Software Phases - Build, Compile, Testing, ...;
- ...

Which is the best Stack for Large-Scale projects on Javascript/Node.js?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first, keep it simple. Every new tool you add is another dependency, and another potential stress point for the project. With that in mind, some good tools, methodologies, and best-practices for server-side javascript development are:

**Folder Structure**
This doesn't *really* matter. Just do what makes sense to you, and what you think will make sense to others if you plan to have collaborators. Search github for Node.JS projects and see how they're structured. I found one good example: https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/nodejs-mongodb-mongoose-restify

**Libraries**
The libraries you use is going to greatly depend on what type of project you're working on. Does the REST API hit a database? Is it MongoDB, redis, MySQL, Neo4J, ... ? You're going to need an interface for that.
Express is a great framework. (I believe it can start a project for you even.)

**Technologies**
Have you considered Coffee/Clojure-script? This extra step at compile time can save you a lot of headaches later on. Your code will also be more readable to others. Jslint is another great tool to verify javascript code. Also, I have to suggest using git for version control. If you aren't: learn it, master it, use it. http://www.git-legit.org/

**Methods**
Your software development strategy will be dependent on what tools you end up using as well as your own personal choices with regard to how you like to write software. I would suggest using Jenkins to continuously integrate your code, and some sort of test framework to ensure what you write is right.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer :)

**Folder Structure** the one that I suggested seems to have a _clean_ and 'readable' structure
**Libraries** I was hoping more advices on this one, not the 'obvious ones', the ones that you suggested depends on the project, I was asking about transversal libraries to every project/app, like RequireJS (as I understand, 'should' be used in every project)
**Technologies** I will have that in consideration ;)
**Methods** I think that on Node.js it's Travis.CI

Comment: RequireJS is certainly a great tool to have, but it is used primarily for client-side Javascript. Node.JS already implements the CommonJS spec so there is no need to use something like Require.JS server-side to add module capabilities.

As for "ubiquitous" libraries. I'd say uglifyjs and jslint are the most widely used. 

You should also checkout [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) which is a fine tool to automate your build process. There are some useful plugins listed on [this page](http://gruntjs.com/plugins).

Comment: what is your opinion about Yeoman? Should I put effort into that?

Comment: Like I said, a lot of this is personal. I tried Yeoman a while back and did not like that it made decisions for me. You may want that, though. Try it! Worse case scenario you learn something, and the only way you're going to figure out the best way to architect your project is to actually dive in and try it.